# Module not found: Can't resolve '@/styles/globals.scss'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, frontend

This is the error message I am getting with my import statement for the scss file in my _app.tsx. How do I resolve this?

I am using Next.js & I've tried almost everything on the web

Comment: Please mention what you have tried specifically.

Comment: Removing @ sign from filepath fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have configured path aliases properly in the `tsconfig.json` file.

```
  ...
  compilerOptions: {
    ...
    baseUrl: '.',
    ...
  }
```